# App crashing instantly after open in Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crash

I have one app in ionic that are stable in the vast majority of my clients.

But i have one client that have one Samsung S9 and when he open the app, instantly open a message:

> The app has stopped

The client confirm that in the older versions the app run normaly.

This is my log available from Google Console:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>
> at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw
>   (DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
>
> at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap (RecordingCanvas.java:97)
>
> at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw
>   (BitmapDrawable.java:529)
>
> at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw (ImageView.java:1367)
>
> at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20338)
>
> at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19283)
>
> at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20061)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4421)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4207)
>
> at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19274)
>
> at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20061)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4421)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4207)
>
> at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19274)
>
> at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20061)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4421)
>
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4207)
>
> at android.view.View.draw (View.java:20341)
>
> at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw (DecorView.java:979)
>
> at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty (View.java:19283)
>
> at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList
>   (ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
>
> at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList
>   (ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
>
> at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw (ThreadedRenderer.java:800)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:3488)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:3275)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:2810)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1779)
>
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:7810)
>
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run
>   (Choreographer.java:911)
>
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:723)
>
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:658)
>
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run
>   (Choreographer.java:897)
>
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (Zygote.java:327)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)

My ionic info:

**Ionic:**

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.1.1 (C:\Users\jsoftwares1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

**Cordova:**

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Cordova Platforms : not available
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 16 other plugins)

**System:**

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\jsoftwares1\Desktop\tools\lib)
NodeJS : v8.11.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 6.4.0
OS : Windows 10

**My cordova plugins:**

```
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 1.11.1 “Advanced HTTP plugin”
cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.1 “Application Events”
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 “AppVersion”
cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.7.2 “BackgroundMode”
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.7 “Badge”
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 “Device”
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 “Notification”
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 “File”
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 “cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard”
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 “cordova-plugin-ionic-webview”
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 “LocalNotification”
cordova-plugin-local-notifications-db 0.8.4 “LocalNotification”
cordova-plugin-sim 1.3.3 “SIM”
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 “Splashscreen”
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 “Whitelist”
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.4.0 “Cordova sqlite storage plugin”
cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 “cordova-support-google-services”
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 “Multidex”
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 “PushPlugin”
```

**My config.xml:**

```
&lt;?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?&gt;

&lt;widget id="japp.jcontrole" version="0.1.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"&gt;

&lt;name&gt;xApp&lt;/name&gt;

&lt;description&gt;Controle de perguntas/respostas auxiliar do sistema xx.&lt;/description&gt;

&lt;author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/"&gt;Ionic Framework Team&lt;/author&gt;

&lt;content src="index.html" /&gt;

&lt;allow-intent href="http://*/*" /&gt;

&lt;allow-intent href="https://*/*" /&gt;

&lt;content src="index.html" /&gt;

&lt;allow-navigation href="*" /&gt;

&lt;allow-intent href="*" /&gt;

&lt;access origin="*" subdomains="true" /&gt;

&lt;allow-intent href="tel:*" /&gt;

&lt;allow-intent href="sms:*" /&gt;

&lt;allow-intent href="mailto:*" /&gt;

&lt;allow-intent href="geo:*" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="SplashScreenSpinnerColor" value="white" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" /&gt;

&lt;preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" /&gt;

&lt;platform name="android"&gt;

&lt;icon qualifier="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" /&gt;

&lt;icon qualifier="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" /&gt;

&lt;icon qualifier="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" /&gt;

&lt;icon qualifier="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" /&gt;

&lt;icon qualifier="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" /&gt;

&lt;icon qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;splash qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" /&gt;

&lt;/platform&gt;

&lt;platform name="ios"&gt;

&lt;icon height="57" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="114" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="40" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="80" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="50" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="100" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="60" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="120" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="180" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="72" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="144" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="76" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="152" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="29" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="58" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" /&gt;

&lt;icon height="87" platform="ios" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" /&gt;

&lt;splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="resources/screens/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" /&gt;

&lt;splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="resources/screens/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" /&gt;

&lt;splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="resources/screens/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" /&gt;

&lt;splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="resources/screens/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" /&gt;

&lt;splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="resources/screens/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" /&gt;

&lt;splash height="768" platform="ios" src="resources/screens/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" /&gt;

&lt;splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="resources/screens/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" /&gt;

&lt;splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="resources/screens/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" /&gt;

&lt;splash height="960" platform="ios" src="resources/screens/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" /&gt;

&lt;splash height="480" platform="ios" src="resources/screens/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" /&gt;

&lt;/platform&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" /&gt;

&lt;allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.15:8100" /&gt;

&lt;allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.15:8101" /&gt;

&lt;allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.15:8102" /&gt;

&lt;allow-navigation href="http://10.0.7.80:8100" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="^1.11.1" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.2.1" /&gt;

&lt;allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.15:8103" /&gt;

&lt;allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.15:8106" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.3.3" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^2.0.1" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="^0.1.9" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-sim" spec="^1.3.3" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notification" spec="^0.9.0-beta.2" /&gt;

&lt;plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.2.3"&gt;

&lt;variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION" value="27.+" /&gt;

&lt;variable name="FCM_VERSION" value="11.6.2" /&gt;

&lt;/plugin&gt;

&lt;plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="^0.7.2" /&gt;

&lt;engine name="browser" spec="5.0.3" /&gt;

&lt;engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5" /&gt;

&lt;engine name="android" spec="7.1.0" /&gt;

&lt;/widget&gt;
Recently i added a background mode with local notifications in one component:

 ngOnInit(): void {

  this.backgroundMode.setDefaults({silent:true});
  this.backgroundMode.enable();
  this.backgroundMode.on("activate").subscribe(()=>{

  this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations()

  clearInterval(this.intervalId); 

  this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {this.consultaNotificacoes()}, 100000);
```

My function that call a local push notification:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < res.data.notificar.perguntas.length; i++) {
            this.localNotifications.schedule({
              id: i+1,
              priority: 2,
              text: 'Produto: ' + res.data.notificar.perguntas[i].produto.substring(0, 20) + '...',
              title: 'Nova pergunta, conta: ' + res.data.notificar.perguntas[i].conta,
              smallIcon: 'res://notification',
            });
          }
        }
```

Comment: HI there! I have the same problem only with Galaxy S8+ and Pixel 2! Did you find any fix? I'm using: ionic:   3.19.0 and cordova: 7.1.0

Comment: yes, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix in config.xml, my assets is wrong.

I do:

```
<platform name="android">
        <icon qualifier="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash qualifier="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
```

and everythings works.

Comment: For me the issue was that I had from another change density instead of qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

For others that get this error, be sure that you define all the densities for `cordova-plugin-splashscreen`. [The documentation's example](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#example-configuration) only mentions 4 densities:

```
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
```

But you need the last two also:

```
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
<splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
```

Even if the device's screen is low (eg. mdpi), **the app will look for higher densities if the user has configured zoom or magnification**. This behavior cannot be reproduced on an emulator, but can cause crashes on physical devices.